# Issues in migrating spring java Neo4j test configuration class from version OGM version 3.2.9 to version 3.2.10

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

my issue is the following : migration from neo4j v3.5.16 to v 4.0.3 doesn't work for my repositories tests.
The current test version is using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

coming with spring boot 2.2.4

Here is the configuration class :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.io.fs.FileUtils;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder;
import org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration

@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.neo4j.interview.api.domain.service" })
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.neo4j.interview.api.repository")
@AutoConfigurationPackage
public class TestConfiguration {

    private static final String TEST_DB_NAME = "test_graph";

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new Builder().build();
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService(), configuration());
        return new SessionFactory(driver, "com.neo4j.interview.api.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        GraphDatabaseService newGraphDatabase = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(TEST_DB_NAME)).newGraphDatabase();
        registerShutdownHook(newGraphDatabase);
        return newGraphDatabase;

    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService managementService) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                managementService.shutdown();
                try {
                    FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(TEST_DB_NAME));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also migrated neo4j from 3.5.16 to 4.0.3

The issue is now `SessionFactory (Driver, String)` does no longer exist in OGM framework which is causing me a headache.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.2.10 the required class are moved to other dependencies :
`org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory` is in this jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And `org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

All these dependencies come with springboot version 2.2.6

But I'm getting this big stacktrace now : it's a typical compatibility issue but I'm using springboot 2.2.6 which means all dependencies are tested.
My question is : Springboot 2.2.6 works with which version of neo4j ? I think 3.5.17 to be confirmed.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction.failure()V
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.transaction.EmbeddedTransaction.rollback(EmbeddedTransaction.java:63) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doRollback(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:322) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:128) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:230) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:441) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:140) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:245) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:255) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:244) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:141) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) ~[.cp/:na]
```

According to Github OGM page [Neo4j-OGM versions](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/wiki/Versions), Spring boot 2.2.6 is compatible.